# clang tool: how to treat .h header as C++ file

Tags: clang, clang-static-analyzer

I am trying with some clang extra tools such like clang-check, but I found it cannot handle .h file as expected, if the file is renamed as .hpp file, it will be OK, but I don't want to change the file extension. Is there any method to let the clang-check to treat .h header as c++ file?

Answer (score 3):

with -extra-arg-before=-xc++ option can resolve my problem

Comment: I tried this on my command line: clang++ -xc++ -std=c++11 -c <my_app.cpp> -o my_app.o; It still complained about a .h file using "#include<string>". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I use `clang-tidy` tool and meet same problem.

`clang-tidy` requires `compile_commands.json` file, and @thisEric mentioned `-xc++` can be put inside this file.

`compile_commands.json` is generated by CMake (*nix) or Clang Power Tools(Visual Studio plugin). When the targets in my CMakeLists.txt consists of .cpp files, it will generate `-x c++` in `compile_commands.json`.

As an example:

`info.h`:

```cpp
#pragma once

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
```

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "info.h"

int main()
{
    struct node n;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(x)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

`.clang-tidy`

```yaml
Checks: '-*,readability-identifier-naming'
CheckOptions:
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.ClassCase
    value:           CamelCase
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.StructCase
    value:           CamelCase
```

By specifying `main.cpp` in CMakeLists.txt, clang-tidy can detect the `struct node`:

[image]